# Change systemd bond0 default bonding

Tags: systemd-networkd, bonding

Using systemd, I can easily create a bond interface i.e. "mybond".

systemd by default creates a bond0 interface, would it be possible to change its parameters?

No matter the .netdev and .network files I create, bond0 is always managed in a round-robin algorithm and with is default parameters.

Are there any ways to change such bond parameters?

Comment: I have never tried `systemd-networkd`. According to the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.netdev.html), you can set the the Name in the [NetDev] Section, and the Mode in the [Bond] section. I would add sample netdev files to the question. Also, is there anything in the journal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution reading [this systemd issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6184).

Adding `options bonding max_bonds=0` in `/etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf`removes the default bond0 interface, so a new custom bond0 interface can be created and its parameters customized